# Can't build a simple React element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. I am trying to export a simple component and display it in the App functional component. However every time I run the code I keep getting this error message:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: . Did you accidentally export a JSX
>   literal instead of a component?

Below is my app component and my test component

```
const App = () => {
  return <Test/>

}

export default App;


import React from 'react';


const Test = () => (<div> Hello </div>)

export default Test();
```

Comment: Did you import ```React``` and ```Test``` in your ```App``` Component?

Answer (score 1):

Remove bracket from your export like below

```
export default Test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const App = () => {
  return <Test/>

}

export default App;


import React from 'react';


const Test = () => (<div> Hello </div>)

export default Test(); // This is wrong 
// We need to export the function definition rather than the executed result
export default Test;
```

Always remember that functions are first-class Objects in JS so they can be

- stored in a variable, object, or array
- Passed as an argument to a function
- Returned from a function

So normally we tend to pass functions (`export default 'function name'` or  `export  'function name'` or `export function () { // your code here}` ) rather than executed result ( `export function_name() // which is initially executing the function and then returning it` )